# python3. Как открыть(получить данные) офисные документы (doc,odt, etc...)

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, open-office

Подскажите, как в **python3**  открыть и получить данные из офисных файлов, таких как odt, doc, docx, rtf. Хотя бы odt.

То что odt  и docx  это по сути архивы в курсе, можно их по идее распаковать, и посмотреть на файл content.xml (если не ошибаюсь), но может есть более современные или удобные способы.

Все что нашел, это для создания таблиц  ods.

Нашел модули **uno**, **pyoo**  и везде описано как создать таблицы, а как получить данные из офисных документов не нашел.

Задача пробежаться по всем существующим в каталоге(подкаталогах) файлах, найти или проанализировать нужное и вывести результат в отдельный файл.

Сейчас подобное частично реализовано на bash'e, хочу переписать все на python3.

Подскажите или покажите как искать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформлю как ответ, чтоб в комментариях не рыскать, если **[tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/tutankhamun)** не против, если против, то в свой ответ добавьте и я свой удалю.

И так, вопрос получилось решить с помощью модуля [ezodf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezodf) ( не много [документации его](https://pythonhosted.org/ezodf/) ). При установке будьте внимательны, если у вас и 2 и 3 версии python, для третьей я ставил так *python3 setup.py install*.

Небольшой пример кода, для наглядности

```
import ezodf
odt = ezodf.opendoc('/home/user/python/text.odt')
list=[]
# Запускаем цикл for  и перебираем все что нашли в файле)
for i in odt.body:
  if i.text == None:
    print('no')
  else:
    list.extend(re.findall(r"[\w']+", i.text.lower()))
```

Поясню, использовал **i.text**  заместо **i.plaintext()**, для ловли нескольких строк со значением **None** (видимо какие то служебные данные, не разбирался), просто **plaintext()** добавляет пустые элементы в список и мне на тот момент показалось,Что через **text**  будет быстрее, но утром могу переосмыслить)

а тут **list.extend(re.findall(r"[\w']+", i.text.lower()))** - с существующему списку list присоединяю или даже так, этим расширяя существующий список list. Выбираю все слова регулярным выражением (каждое слово из документа в список), применяю к ним нижний регистр и все.

так это только кусок, потому может смотреться не очень, и многое что можно добавить, но по крайней мере теперь понятно как читать документы.

Спасибо
**[tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/tutankhamun)** за подсказки.

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот навскидку пара библиотек:

1. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezodf
2. https://github.com/eea/odfpy

Конечно работать через сервисы OpenOffice - более правильный путь самурая, но для этого нужен хотя бы "безголовый" OpenOffice, а его может не оказаться. Кроме того, мне кажется, сервисы OpenOffice будут разочаровывать показателями производительности при обработке большого количества файлов, но вы получите полный функционал.

Кстати нужно учитывать что при использовании OpenOffice придется руководствоваться документацией по Java API и адаптировать ее под Python

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо... мне пока нужно прочитать файл и и сделать выборку... а там посмотрим

Comment: Смог создавать, и вносить изменения.. а вот читать файлы odt  не могу ... вроде и есть там body, content  и у них text -  в ответ либо none,  либо <ezodf.body.TextBody object at 0x7fbabf2db208>...  в пример на гитхабе только как вносить изменения и создавать.. а как читать нет ... не востребованная видать задача)

Comment: Странно. А вот эта строка `pi = sheet[1, 1].value`  как раз чтение из ячейки. В [документации](http://pythonhosted.org/ezodf/) есть явные примеры чтения. Может вы расширите ваш вопрос на предмет "найти или проанализировать нужное" или напишиет новый? Тогда будет более понятно в каком объеме вам нужен функционал и я смог бы тогда хоть пример написать.

Comment: из таблицы могу получить данные, а вот из простого документа нет)  pi = sheet[1, 1].value - это с таблицей сработало... по-идее doc = opendoc('file.odt')    doc.body.text  или doc.conent.text  должн помочь ..но они выводят None,  хотя файл с текстом. Весь текст документа надо загнать в список/словать, вот что надо... если кратко

Comment: Про `doc.body.text` нигде не нашел, а вот если запустить `for` по итератору `doc.body` можно найти элементы с нужным контентом

Comment: да,через for  сработало... for i in doc.body:
...   print(i.text)
... 
None
Text 
разный текст
None
None тольо видимо три None  это его служебная информация... а так .. уже хорошо...

Comment: Попробуйте `for i in doc.body: print(i.plaintext())`

Comment: да,через planetext  он выдает тоже самое, но без None,  хотя строки пустые выводит ... сейчас еще попробую... Спасибо

Comment: и не пойму как закрывать файлы открытые, чтоб без сохранения, close()  нету)